# 規則に違反してはいけない。に or を？

Tags: grammar, particles

I'm confused if I should use に or を in this sentence. (Also if は/が could fit here).

Comment: "に" is correct here as in the answer below, and you can also simply say "規則違反してはいけない".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 「規則{きそく}**に**違反{いはん}してはいけない。」
>
> "One should not violate the rules."

Or more literally,

> "It is no good to violate the rules."

It technically needs to be 「に」 because 「違反する」 is an ***intransitive*** verb.  Some people might actually use 「を」 instead in real life, but that would be a substandard usage.

Using「が」 instead of 「に」 is impossible because 「規則」 is not the subject of the sentence in the first place.  The subject is unmentioned.

Using 「は」 would be "correct by popular vote".  You will hear us say that.  The "more correct" way to use a 「は」 would be to do so together with 「に」 as in:

> 「規則**には**違反してはいけない。」

Comment: 規則には違反してはいけない makes a lot of sense, but 違反 is a する verb, how'd I even know its transitivity... That's why I got confused if you could use を here.

Comment: @user27223 A good dictionary such as 明鏡国語辞典 will tell you the transitivity of 違反する, which marks 違反 as 〔名・自サ変〕.